# How to setup boot scripts to save orphan inodes after improper shutdown?

Tags: boot, shutdown, fsck, inode, dmesg

after abnormal shutdown in dmesg I have

```
[   16.107445] EXT4-fs (dm-1): INFO: recovery required on readonly filesystem
[   16.107450] EXT4-fs (dm-1): write access will be enabled during recovery
[   16.993559] EXT4-fs (dm-1): orphan cleanup on readonly fs
[   17.247792] EXT4-fs (dm-1): 25 orphan inodes deleted
[   17.247796] EXT4-fs (dm-1): recovery complete
[   17.518767] EXT4-fs (dm-1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
```

is it possible to do not delete but save data from orphaned inodes?

(Linux Mint 16)

Answer (score 0):

Given EXT4 is journaled, it's unlikely that you lost any data in the process.  Having orphaned inodes after an abnormal shutdown is normal (see [Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/113322/diagnosing-cause-of-orphaned-inodes-on-linux-busy-mysql)) so those inodes are probably related to temporary files that won't give you much back if you were able to recover them.

In short, you probably could, but it's unlikely you'd want them.

Comment: yes, unlikely but possible, before the last case I never got something bad, but in the last case I lost firefox and jedit sessions and unsaved changes, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: Could those sessions be in memory rather than on disk?